# Pulling Flickr image title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, random, flickr

My javascript is pulling single Flickr images randomly on each refresh. I would like to also display the image title (preferably on rollover) too. Been looking for hours on how to do this but not getting anywhere (don't really know js).

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=63338473@N03&tags=webhomeug&format=json&jsoncallback=?", displayImages);

var count = 0;                              
var htmlString = "<ul>";

function displayImages(data){
  if(count <= 0){
      var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*($(data.items).size()));
      var img = (data.items[ranNum].media.m).replace("_m.jpg", "_b.jpg");
      var link  = data.items[ranNum].link;
      var title = data.items[ranNum].title;

        htmlString += '<img src="' + img + '" alt="' + title + '" title="' + title + '" class=vtip"/>';
        count++;
        displayImages(data);
    }else{
      htmlString += '</ul>'
      $('#images').html(htmlString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unsure what the question is here. Do you want to know the javascript to show a tooltip type rollover, or are you saying you are unable to get the title (from the code it appears this would be fine).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("selectYourPhoto").attr("title");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

The suggested code wasn't working for me, but after looking into the attr method I found this works perfectly...

```
 $("div").text($("img").attr("title"));
```

Thanks again!